# 2.91 - where can I change animation size

Tags: animation, resolution

I just want to change the output of the rendered animation (CTRL+F12)

- it used to be accessible, but I cannot find it anymore
- where can I post a feature request so that the dev's make it even more hidden and cryptic ?

I tried looking in blender of course, then outlook, and thunderbird, I tried "device manager" in windows, and I tried to search for these settings on my android phone....one never knows

next step, I'll apply for a trip on mars, these settings got to be there...everywhere but in blender since v 2.8

thanks

Comment: The Output tab is under the Render tab in the Properties panel, it's not part of the Render tab anymore

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's right there, where the red circle is.